# karate UI driver not available in called feature

Tags: karate

So I have below UI test scenario where the first step is to login user, then do something and last step is logout. Both login and logout are in their respective feature files. The login step works but when call is made to `user-logout.feature`, I get error:
`javascript evaluation failed: driver.click('#user-dropdown'), ReferenceError: "driver" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1`.
Just wondering if my approach is incorrect? driver configured in the login feature is available in the ui-test feature but is not available further in the user-logout feature?.

I am on version 0.9.4.

Below are my scenarios:

**ui-test.feature**

```
Feature: UI test feature

  Background:
    # appUrl from config
    * url appUrl

  Scenario: Login as non-admin user
    # Login
    * call read('classpath:common/ui/user-login.feature') { user: 'ui-tester', password: 'password' }
    # Do something
    And driver.click('.button-toolbar.btn.btn-primary')
    # Logout
    * call read('classpath:common/ui/user-logout.feature')
```

**user-login.feature**

```
Feature: Login user

  Background:
    * url appUrl
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }

  Scenario: Login user with the given username and password
    Given driver appUrl
    And driver.input('#login-username', __arg.user)
    And driver.input('#login-password', __arg.password)
    And driver.submit('.btn-primary.btn.btn-default')
```

**user-logout.feature**

```
Feature: Logout user from application

  Scenario: Logout user
    * driver.click('#user-dropdown')
    * driver.click('#logout-button')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this version 0.9.5.RC4 please. If this is not fixed, then we have this open issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/969

Please use 0.9.5.RC4 or greater, a lot of UI fixes are only in this version for now. Full docs are here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core

Comment: using 0.9.5.RC4 fixes this. Also the updated UI documentation looks good. Waiting for production ready release.